# PayPal Preapproval card checking?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-adaptive-payments

Does the `PayPal Classic API` for `Adaptive Payments` do any checking on credit cards that get preapproved?

My customers preapprove their card and then when I use the preapproval id to charge them I sometimes get the error:

```
This transaction cannot be processed. Please enter a valid credit card number and type
```

Is there anyway to ensure the credit card entered is valid when they create the preapproval in order to avoid this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're looking at the error# 580036 - which is generic decline error message. This means that PayPal has tried to contact the issuing bank to collect the funds, but the payment was declined. 
To list a couple of reasons:

- Usually because there aren't enough funds available
- it may be down to security algorithms within the bank.
- Certain card issuers will decline certain Merchant Category Codes (e.g. Adult Content) depending on the card being used (e.g. Business Credit Cards)

When you create a Pre-Approval, you're creating a payment agreement with the PayPal Account, but there is no direct contact with the issuing bank at this point. As such, if the Pre-Approval fails at this point, the merchant needs to get in touch with the buyer and either agree on a new form of payment or clear the issues on the account.

The credit card linked to the respective PayPal account is valid nonetheless.

Comment: I ended up just running a 1 cent pay call immediately, if that completes then I keep the preapproval.

Comment: Any idea why a preapproval would pass my 1 cent check, but fail on another pay call?